# emr-5.4.0 (Spark executors memory allocation issue)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I created a spark cluster(learning so did not create high memory-cpu cluster) with 1 master node and 2 Core to run executors using below config

Master:Running1m4.large (2 Core , 8GB)
Core:Running2c4.large  (2 core , 3.5 GB)
Hive 2.1.1, Pig 0.16.0, Hue 3.11.0, Spark 2.1.0, Sqoop 1.4.6, HBase 1.3.0

When pyspark is run getting below error
 *Required executor memory (1024+384 MB) is above the max threshold (896 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.*

Before trying to increase yarn-site.xml config , curious to understand why EMR is taking just 896MB as limit when master has 8GB and worker node has 3.5GB each.

And Resource manager URL (for master-   http://master-public-dns-name:8088/) is showing 1.75 GB where as memory for vm is 8GB. Is hbase or other sws taking up too much memory?

If anyone encountered similar issue , please share your insight why it is EMR is setting low defaults. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Before trying to increase yarn-site.xml config , curious to understand
>   why EMR is taking just 896MB as limit when master has 8GB and worker
>   node has 3.5GB each.

If you run spark jobs with yarn cluster mode (which you probably were using) , the executors will be run on core's and masters memory will not be used.

Now, all-though your CORE EC2 instance (c4.large)  has 3.75 GB to use, EMR configures YARN not to use all this memory for running YARN containers or spark executors. This is because you gotta leave enough memory for other permanent daemons ( like HDFS's datanode , YARN's nodemanager , EMR's own daemons etc.. based on app's you provision)

EMR does publish this default YARN configuration it sets for all instance types on this page : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html

c4.large

```
Configuration Option    Default Value   
mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx717m    
mapreduce.map.memory.mb 896
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb    1792
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb 1792
```

So,  yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 1792, which means 1792 MB is the physical memory that will be allocated to YARN containers on that core node having 3.75 actual memory. Also,  check spark-defaults.xml where EMR has some defaults for spark executor memory. These are default's and of course you can change those  before starting cluster using EMR's configurations API . But keep in mind that if you over provision memory for YARN containers , you might starve some other processes.

Given that it is important to understand  YARN configs and how SPARK interacts with YARN .

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a property of EMR but rather of YARN, which is the resource manager running on EMR.

My personal take on YARN is that is really build for managing long running clusters that continuously take in a variety of jobs that it has to run simultaneously. In these cases it makes sense for YARN to only assign a small part of the available memory to each job.

Unfortunately, when it comes to specific-purpose clusters (like: "I will just spin up a cluster run my job and terminate the cluster again") these YARN-defaults are simply annoying, and you have to configure a bunch of stuff in order to make YARN utilise your resources optimally. But running on EMR it's what we are stuck with these days, so one has to live with that...